# JavaScript multiple promise issue with $.get

Tags: javascript

```
function getHiddenTable(){
    var url = ".......";
    var apptoken = "blahblah";
    return $.get(url, {
        act: "API_DoQuery",
        clist: "7.8.6",
        data: apptoken
    });
}

function getRprTable(){
    var url = "........";
    var apptoken = "blahblah";
    return $.get(url, {
        act: "API_DoQuery",
        clist: "3.60",
        data: apptoken
    });
}

function main(){
    getHiddenTable().then(function(xml_hidden){
        hiddenTable = xml_hidden;
        console.dirxml(hiddenTable);
        return getRprTable();
    }).then(function(xml_rpr){
        rprTable = xml_rpr;
        console.dirxml(rprTable);
    });
}

main();
```

getHiddenTable() returns a $.get request and getRprTable() also returns a $.get request

Both of these functions return two separate xml files that contain different data. I assign both xml files to two separate global variables so they have scope to other function that I need to use them in. However, both console statements display the initial request from getHiddenTable(). But why? And what can I do to fix this?

**Update**

Hey guys, thanks for the help. I found out my problem with much frustration and actually utilized $.when, from the person who provided the idea in the comments.

```
$.when(getHiddenTable(), getRprTable()).done(function(xml_hidden, xml_rpr){
   console.dirxml(xml_hidden[0]);
   console.dirxml(xml_rpr[0]);
});
```

Accessing the data value of the callback function objects can be done by simply accessing the 0th index.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked on the server-side that the two API calls really return different content? Also, unrelated but maybe helpful: since you apparently use jQuery, you can apply `$.when` to run the two queries in parallel: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: Both `then`s are bound to the promise returned by `getHiddenTable`, before the contents of either are run.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely want to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to run multiple promises at once and return the results of all the promises once they have all finished.

Example:

```
Promise.all([getHiddenTable(), getRprTable()])
.then(function(results) {
  let hiddenTable = results[0];
  let rprTable = results[1];
  // do stuff with your results
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work and produces the same result. Also, I added code to both functions to ensure that each API call produces unique results and they do. It's not until I chain these promises together that they produce the same result, which I don't understand. Every guide I have read so far uses this idea but apparently I am doing something wrong.